# I want to add id to my table in a sorted way

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite

My table is like this

```
   release
   b
   c
   a
   e
   f
   q
```

I want to add id according to their name in a sorted way from a to z,like this

```
   release    id
   b          2
   c          3
   a          1
   e          4
   f          5
   q          6
```

How to do this?

Comment: now, I can just add id from 1 to 6 ,but this is just according to their row number , I want to add id according to their release

Comment: another solution is to change data in release. sort them from a to z and save data in table. so that I can add id according to row number

Comment: what db you are using?

Comment: Which database are you using?  The answer will depend...

Comment: I am using sqlite browser to this. the database is sqlite. but I'm studying Oracle. It is OK to use Oracle command. and the data type of release is text. I don't know if '>',' <' this symbol can work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Query**:

```
MERGE INTO table_name d
USING ( SELECT ROWID,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY release ) AS id
        FROM table_name ) s
ON ( d.ROWID = s.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET id = s.id;
```

**Oracle and SQLite Query**:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET id = (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM   table_name b
          WHERE  table_name.release >= b.release);
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0e619/1)

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. but using select doesn't actually changed data in table. I am trying to use update and order by. But I haven't worked out..

Comment: @user92322 Updated to use `UPDATE`.